# Erlang compiler keeps throwing strange syntax error

Tags: erlang, syntax-error

So, I am making a tic-tac-toe game in Erlang and it keeps throwing a syntax error and I don't know why. It happens in the function to check if X wins. Here's the code:

```erlang
checkX(["xxx" | _]) -> true;
checkX([_ | ["xxx" | _]]) -> true;
checkX([_ | [_ | ["xxx" | _]]]) -> true;
checkX(Board) ->
    if 
        xy(Board, {0, 0}) == 120 and xy(Board, {0, 1}) == 120 and xy(Board, {0, 2}) == 120 -> true;

        xy(Board, {1, 0}) == 120 and xy(Board, {1, 1}) == 120 and xy(Board, {1, 2}) == 120 -> true;

        xy(Board, {2, 0}) == 120 and xy(Board, {2, 1}) == 120 and xy(Board, {2, 2}) == 120 -> true;

        xy(Board, {0, 0}) == 120 and xy(Board, {1, 1}) == 120 and xy(Board, {2, 2}) == 120 -> true;

        xy(Board, {2, 0}) == 120 and xy(Board, {1, 1}) == 120 and xy(Board, {0, 2}) == 120 -> true;

       true -> false

    end.
```

(`xy/2` is a function that takes a board (which is a list of strings) and a tuple and returns the character at the position in the tuple.) It keeps throwing this error when I compile it:

```
board.erl:68: syntax error before '=='
```

(line 68 is the first condition in the if statement.)

Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 4):

`and` binds tighter than `==`.  Here are the implicit parentheses in your guard:

```
xy(Board, {0, 0}) == (120 and xy(Board, {0, 1}))
```

which is not what you intended.  Your whole guard ends up being similar to:

```
if 
   Board == 2 == 3 -> true;
   true -> false
end
```

which produces the same error.  You can fix the error with some parentheses:

```
if 
   (Board == 2) == 3 -> true;
   true -> false
end
```

However, even if you add parentheses to your guard, you will then encounter the next error with your guard.  See [erlang guards](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#guard-sequences) in the docs.  To wit, you can't call just any function in a guard--there are only a limited number of functions that can be called in a guard, and the allowed functions are listed in the docs.

I suggest you start with a `,` instead of `and` when writing guards, then adjust if you need something else, e.g. [andalso](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2014-May/079145.html).

Comment: Thanks! In most other languages the `==` binds tighter than the and operator, so I was a bit confused there.